Need help creating Voroni with imported model
I have imported an STL (basically a bell shape with a hole in top) and followed some tutorials but I am not getting the result I am after. The STL import is in the first image and result is in the second image using the shown modifiers. I seem to get two layers of voroni since the imported shape has an inside and outside surface and I only want a single layer. I also want the whole thing to be random openings like what is happening near the top. 
Also blender is putting in some unexpected elements shown by the red arrow.  Any help would be appreciated. 

Hello. What do you mean by "I only want a single layer"? Just delete the inner layer then so you only have the outer layer. Also would be helpful to share the STL file.

could you please share your file?
